# Routing desktop to webcam on a mac

Tags: macos, mac, desktop, webcam

My girlfriend would like to broadcast her desktop on ustream. We have tried camtwist, and being a PC user myself, I am totally out of ideas since that didn't work. (Flash could only detect the iSight device, and not the camtwist "device".

Are there any alternatives or probable cause/solutions?

Flash is updated to the latest version after reading that some people fixed the issue this way

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: http://www.ustream.tv/producer

"Capture video and audio from programs on your computer or broadcast whatever you are browsing on the web. With Producer 2.0 you can broadcast the screen of any computer that is on your local network, making this computer an additional input source for Producer. If the other computer does not have Producer installed, download Desktop Presenter for free and install this on the computer you would like to use as a source."

Halfway down there is a link for Screencasting.  Under its description: download PC or MAC version

Hope this helps

Comment: @zeta if this helps +1 :D